# How to extract certain letters from a string using Python

Tags: python, list

I have a string 'A1T1730'

From this I need to extract the second letter and the last four letters. For example, from  'A1T1730' I need to extract '1' and '1730'. I'm not sure how to do this in Python.

I have the following right now which extracts every character from the string separately so can someone please help me update it as per the above need.

```
list = ['A1T1730']  
for letter in list[0]:  
      print letter
```

Which gives me the result of A, 1, T, 1, 7, 3, 0

Comment: I think we need more information about the pattern of the data. A solution can be found for the data provided, but it could be that it doesn't work for any other case you might have.

Comment: 1, 7, 3, and 0 are not letters. Also, don't name a list `list`, that shadows a builtin type.

Answer (score 5):

```
my_string = "A1T1730"
my_string = my_string[1] + my_string[-4:]
print my_string
```

**Output**

```
11730
```

If you want to extract them to different variables, you can just do

```
first, last = my_string[1], my_string[-4:]
print first, last
```

**Output**

```
1 1730
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) with [`str.isdigit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.isdigit) (as unbound method form):

```
>>> filter(str.isdigit, 'A1T1730')
'11730'
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, 'A1T1730')) # In Python 3.x
'11730'
```

If you want to get numbers separated, use regular expression (See [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', 'A1T1730')
['1', '1730']
```

Use thefourtheye's solution if the positions of digits are fixed.

---

BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows [builtin `list` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Comment: Downvoter: How can I improve the answer? If there's anything wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do like this

```py
_2nd = lsit[0][1]

# last 4 characters
numbers = list[0][-4:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `isdigit()`. If that character is a digit it returns true and otherwise returns false:

```py
list = ['A1T1730']  
for letter in list[0]:
    if letter.isdigit() == True:
        print letter, #The coma is used for print in the same line
```

I hope this useful.